# Ask for a study path to simulate water like this

Tags: simulation

I am interested in simulating water movement like this:

1:45 to 3:05 of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbrFIp73tbw

I have learnt a lot of computer graphics so far, for example:

1. Interactive Computer Graphics: A Top-Down Approach with Shader-Based
   OpenGL, 6th Edition, by Edward Angel and Dave Shreiner
2. Fluid Simulation for Computer Graphics, 2nd Edition, by Robert
   Bridson

, as well as other math books on e.g. linear algebra and numerical PDE solvers. They are all good books and I learnt lots of foundations of computer graphics from them, but it seems that they are too basic to be useful. So far, I still have no idea how to implement the video clip mentioned above. I know I still have a lot to learn and need to continue to invest vast time and efforts, but I hope my time and efforts devoted are not deviating from what I am aiming at. So, in order for me to implement the above water simulation, what is the shortest but sufficient study path, that is, what books and/or papers I need to read?

A side note: the video implemented bubbles, but after splashing onto the wall, some water blobs should stick on the wall and flow down slowly, assuming the wall is plastic. This was not implemented. I want to make that effects myself too.

Thank you for pointing me a correct direction.

Comment: Nvidia Flex uses positional based fluids (PBF) for simulations and a variation of screen space fluids (SSF) for rendering fluids. Rendering and simulating fluids are two very separate tasks. Just start looking at some fluid simulation code on github and connect the ideas from books/papers/ppts to the code. In particular, the video shows PBF and SSF. But there are many other fluid simulation techniques like FLIP and SPH. http://mmacklin.com/pbf_sig_preprint.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the information, Mr. Wilson. I will take a look at all these techniques and try them all.